# Get out of Navigation Controller with Segue

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, segue

Here is the situation: I have a start screen where I can put some data in it that is used for a Navigation Controller. I connected the ViewController (start screen) with the Navigation Controller via a Segue and it works pretty good. But now I am looking for a solution to get back to the start screen without still being in that Navigation Controller Interface.
I am pretty sure there is already a question in StackOverflow, but I could not find it. I would be very thankful you rather link the question or if it is not in Stackoverflow help me out.

Thanks :)

Comment: Search for "unwind segue".

Comment: Thanks, that was also very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you presented the NavigationController with a modal segue.
If this is the case you can call dismiss when you are ready to go back to starting view controller.

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for